# Working out how much time has increased by in %

Tags: percentages

I have two time values:

Previous
3d 5h

Now
5d 7h

How can I work out how much it has changed by in terms of percentage.

Thanks

Comment: How would you usually go about working out how much something has changed by in terms of percentage? Say, if something has increased from 3 to 5? Time values are no different from anything else, really.

Comment: Do you know how to work out percentage increase for plain numbers? Like if $20$ increased to $30$, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous: $77$ hours, now: $127$ hours.

Thus, $127/77=1+50/77$, so this is an increase of $50/77\approx 65\%$.

Comment: Thank you very much. If say it was 77/127 which is 61%, do I say the time has decreased by 39%?

Comment: From $127$ to $77$ hours? Yes, then the time decreased by $\approx 39\%$.